# Should I open a deferred annuity with my Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, investing, ira, annuity

first post here...
I want to open a Roth IRA with TIAA (I have a 403b with them). I have to fill out the paper form and additional forms since I am from NY. I was sent the Roth IRA enrollment form which was easy enough. However, I was also sent a deferred annuity enrollment form for Roth IRA which is where I got confused.

I wasn't sure if this was necessary and I don't even really know what it is. I called the company to inquire and was told that I should fill out the annuity form if I want more investing options in my Roth IRA down the line? Like real estate? I was also told there was no downside to having the annuity with my Roth IRA and no cost. Is this true and therefore I should just open the annuity? Maybe I am overanalyzing, but I just wanted confirmation before filling out the annuity enrollment form for Roth IRA.

Comment: This sounds sketchy to me. Annuities are notorious for being a bad deal for everyone except the people selling them.

Comment: Anyone else have thoughts?

Comment: May thought is the same as John's: annuities are good for TIAA, so they're trying to get you to buy into one by sending the enrollment form along with the Roth form.

Comment: Thanks guys. What negative would it have for me?

Comment: There is no reason to open a Roth IRA with TIAA just because you have a 403(b) plan with them (actually, it is your university or school or nonprofit hospital that has established the 403(b) plan with TIAA). There is very little reason to invest your Roth IRA in an annuity regardless of whether you go with TIAA or some other investment company. Yes, it is convenient to have all your assets with one company, but the downsides can (and in this case do) outweigh the benefits, and especially so if you are being encouraged to invest your Roth IRA in an annuity.

Comment: What are the downsides of the annuity with the Roth IRA